# How to evaluate this formula right in apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In Microsoft Office Excel,I set this formula in a cell.`=YEAR("2017-01-01")`.The result is `2017`.
In apache-poi,I do the same.

```
cell.setCellFormula("YEAR(\"2017-01-01\")");
```

But I get a wrong result.

```
#VALUE!
```

How to get the correct result?
Code

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = hssfworkbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellFormula("YEAR(\"2017-01-01\")");
CreationHelper creationHelper = hssfworkbook.getCreationHelper();
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();
System.out.println(evaluator.evaluate(cell));
```

Console

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [#VALUE!]
```

use apache-poi 3.16

Comment: Excels [YEAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9) expects a `Serial_number` as its argument and not a `String`. Maybe Excel itself will be so tolerant and converts "2017-01-01" to a date serial number before using in `Year`. But `apache poi` will not do so. So do `cell.setCellFormula("YEAR(DATE(2017,1,1))");` as suggested in Excels help file for `Year`.

Answer (score 1):

From Interface FormulaEvaluator docs

> If cell contains formula, it evaluates the formula, and puts the formula result back into the cell, in place of the old formula. Else if cell does not contain formula, this method leaves the cell unchanged. Note that the same instance of Cell is returned to allow chained calls like:
>
> ```
> int evaluatedCellType = evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType();
> ```

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
{
     cell = evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
}
```

Comment: It does not help.I think apache poi can not support converting a `string` to a `date serial_number` as @Axel Richter said.I have decided to use `cell.setCellFormula("YEAR(DATE(2017,1,1))");` instead.